# The meeting IS TO take place at 10 pm

Tags: infinitives, be, periphrastic-modals

The meeting **is to** take place at 10 pm
Should "Is to" be mean here as "have to" or "going to"?
Another example:
Those of you, who sign up **are to be** commended. 
This kind of sentences confusing me a bit) What rules in action here?

Comment: http://www.grammaring.com/be-to-infinitive

Comment: The capitalisation of IS TO at least hints at the illocutionary act Amadan mentions, though I suspect it is merely meant to highlight the string. But see what Jasper says about that.

Answer (score 3):

It can be used in two meanings:

- More commonly as a statement of expectation, pretty much equivalent to "The meeting is supposed/expected/scheduled to take place at 10 pm".
- Less commonly as an illocutionary act: "I hereby declare that the meeting shall take place at 10 pm". Compare with a bit more salient "The defendant is to pay $5000 in damages to the plaintiff *(bam)*".

Comment: Apparently, according to Searle's classification, these **both** fall in the 'illocutionary act' speech act classification. The first is subclass assertive, the second subclass directive. Previously, I'd only come across the 'illocutionary act = speech act that [instantaneously and unavoidably] changes the reality in accord with the proposition of the declaration' [Wikipedia] usage; in Searle's [1975] classification, this is the declaration subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially (and semantically), *is to* here functions like *will* (synonymous with *going to*):

The meeting will take place at 10p.m.

However, your organization of what goes with what is a little off. *To* doesn't go with *is* but rather belongs with *take* (to take). *To* is the infinitive marker (to be, to hold, to laugh, etc.).

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613772/2085).